# Modify pagination limit in admin (Custom options)

Tags: magento2

I want to modify Customizable options pagination. Currently on 1 page by default we can see 20 options and the 21st will be on next page i.e. page 2. I need to see 100 options on page 1 & 101 on page 2. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by doing two way by over writing  this file and changing direct in core file on the following this location :

**First Method :**

```
path : vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows

file : dynamic-rows.js //on line number 159 http://prntscr.com/os1ay9 
        pages: 1,
        pageSize: 100,//you can change here as you want page size limit
        relatedData: [],
        currentPage: 1,
        recordDataCache: [],
        startIndex: 0
```

**Second Method :**

create new file in your module :

```
**Path** : app/code/[vendor]/[module_name]/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows": "[vendor]_[module_name]/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows",
        }
    }
}
```

create new file in your module one more and paste magento old code and replace according to your requirement  :

```
app/code/[vendor]/[module_name]/view/adminhtml/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows.js
```